# Insert array data into html table column using php

Tags: php, html, arrays

There are quite a few of question for similar purpose but I cannot find any solution. I am hoping someone can point me to the right direction. I am trying to insert couple of arrays into a column but only the array values into each column, not the index (the index is required part number). Here is my code:

```
        $Asset['MAINS_RD'] = 'main water supply';
        $Asset['OTHER_CB'] = 'Other Water Supplies';
        $Asset['CWST_CB'] = 'Number of Cold Water Tanks';
        $Number['MAINS_NUM'] = '1';
        $Number['OTHER_NUM'] = '1';
        $Number['CWST_NUM'] = '5';
        $serviceRegister = [
            'assets' => $Asset,
            'number_present' => $Number
        ];
        echo '<table>';
        foreach($serviceRegister as $source){
            foreach($source as $rows=>$row){
                echo '<tr>';
                    echo "<td>" .$rows."</td>";
                    echo "<td>" .$row."</td>";
                echo '</tr>';

            }
        }
        echo '</table>';
```

and the result is:

```
MAINS_RD    main water supply
OTHER_CB    Other Water Supplies
CWST_CB     Number of Cold Water Tanks
MAINS_NUM   1
OTHER_NUM   1
CWST_NUM    5
```

And my expected result is:

```
main water supply             1
Other Water Supplies          1
Number of Cold Water Tanks    5
```

Most of the solution I found is to but array input rows but I cannot find a php solution to do what I want to do. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should make the keys match up. There currently is no relation between the index in one array and the other. `$Asset['MAINS'] = 'main water supply'` and `$Number['MAINS'] = '1';` then just iterate over 1 and use the key to pull the value from the other

Comment: Thank you for reply. I cannot change the index. It is a fixed value from data base. I cannot show you the exact code but it is very similar. It has to be MAINS_CB and MAINS_NUM, they cannot be changed.

Comment: `MAINS_RD = MAINS_NUM` , `MAINS_NUM=OTHER_NUM` use PHP to accord the results as possible

Answer (score 0):

I find you requirements to be really unattractive and confusing.  I wouldn't invite this sort of XY Problem into a professional script.  I don't understand your motivations, but here is one way to re-assign/align the keys of the two arrays and iterate using just one loop without completely refactoring your code.

This assume that the two arrays will have an equal length of elements.
I have no idea how your input data will vary and I little confidence that this solution will hold up over time.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/NFVbX))

```
$Asset['MAINS_RD'] = 'main water supply';
$Asset['OTHER_CB'] = 'Other Water Supplies';
$Asset['CWST_CB'] = 'Number of Cold Water Tanks';
$Number['MAINS_NUM'] = '1';
$Number['OTHER_NUM'] = '1';
$Number['CWST_NUM'] = '5';

$Number = array_combine(array_keys($Asset), $Number);

echo '<table>';
foreach ($Asset as $column => $value) {
    echo '<tr>';
        echo "<td>" . $value . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $Number[$column] . "</td>";
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

Output:

```
main water supply           1
Other Water Supplies        1
Number of Cold Water Tanks  5
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. I am actually doing the same thing as your code and produce the same result. Someone gave me those arrays and simply asking me to create a table in put into a report. The backend of his interface is to have a check box on the asset data and receive the number input only when it is checked. This is why he has index for one data only. That is why the array is looking this way.

Comment: You may accept my answer if I have resolved your question.